# How to resolve auth failure when setting up remote interpreter in IntelliJ

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, vagrant

I am trying to set up a remote interpreter in IntelliJ.

I go through the following steps:

- Go to Project Settings
- Go to Project SDK
- Create a new Remote Ruby SDK
- Press the "Vagrant" radio button
- Navigate to my vagrant folder
- Press "Ok"

When I do this, I get an error:

```
Can't create Ruby SDK
Auth fail
```

In the logs, I get this message:

```
2015-12-22 10:25:03,624 [1409673]   INFO - e.RemoteSdkCredentialsProducer - Credentials for VagrantBasedCredentialsHolder{myVagrantFolder='/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Code/vagrant', myMachineName='null'} found in cache.
```

If I `ssh` into the vagrant host URL it lists, I can `ssh` in no problem.

*I suspect that the problem is related to `myMachineName='null'`, however I have no idea.*

How can I resolve this `Auth fail`?